# how to determine if a layer has been added to a scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Apologies if this sounds too simple but I've not been able to find a solution. I am working with several layers in my game. How I can determine if a layer has been added to a scene?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to achieve. For example, if you just need to do something inside your layer after it is added to the scene(run animation, for example), you can use it's `onEnter` method. If you want to check if your method was added to the scene, you can get all children of your scene and check each of them, for example, with `isKindOfClass:` message

Comment: send an NSNotification on add, and/or override the scene's addChild method

Answer (score 0):

try this, assuming that your [MenuManager sharedMenuManager] is the layer in question:

```
if (![MenuManager sharedMenuManager].parent) {
    // has not been added before
}
```